# MonoGame Adding texture

Tags: textures, monogame

I am learning c# with MonoGame. 
How do I load texture in this class ? I cannot use this.Content.Load("texture");

```
public class Mob1
{
    Texture2D texture;
    public float X;
    public float Y;

    public Mob1(float x, float y, Texture2D texture)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.texture = texture;
    } 

    public Mob1()
    {
        this.X = 50;
        this.Y = 50;
        this.texture = ???;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to consider the code that calls the constructor of your `Mob1` class. Where are you going to call `new Mob1()`?

Let's say for example you create new mobs in the `LoadContent` method of your `Game` class.

```
public void LoadContent()
{
    var mob = new Mob1();
}
```

At this point you've got a couple of choices.

You could use the first constructor and pass in the texture along with the X and Y values:

```
var texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("mob1");
var mob = new Mob1(15, 15, texture);
```

Or you could change the second constructor to take a `ContentManager` as a parameter:

```
public Mob1(ContentManager content)
{
    this.X = 50;
    this.Y = 50;
    this.texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("mob1");
}
```

Then your call in `LoadContent` becomes:

```
var mob = new Mob1(Content);
```

Personally, I prefer the first constructor because it properly decouples the `Mob1` class from the `ContentManager`. On the other hand some people prefer the second approach because they can define the "data" inside the class itself. This is really a design choice and you have to make it yourself.

The point is, you'll need to pass the texture into the class somehow. These are not you're only options but they are the least likely to get you into trouble later down the line.

Someone might bring up *singletons*, *service locators* or *property injection* which are also valid options here, but be careful with these patterns if you don't understand them. They can sometimes *feel* like better options but they also come with some significant downsides that aren't obvious up front.

I understand you're still new to C# and I've brought up some fairly advanced topics here. You can always Google the terms I've mentioned if you don't know what they are. Honestly though, don't worry about it too much. Just pick something and go with it. That's the best way to learn.